# Creating a custom server role in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, roles

I'm a sys admin of a web farm, and currently my developers can connect to the SQL server as sysadmins.

Now, i want them to be able to connect to all DB's but only have permission to modify the DB Schema and such, NOT create new DB's or change permissions.

is there anyway i can create a custom Server Role and configure what permissions it have?

Comment: wouldn't groups of devs be assigned to individual databases? surely not all devs work on all databases? Come to think of it! Why are you letting devs alter schema: get them to script changes, place those in SCC and give them to DBA to deploy...

Comment: The problem is were not such a big company and our dev team consists of only 5 ppl, so they also alter the DB and develop the application. They need the access to the DB but not COMPLETE access.

Comment: and how do you (and they) work out when a chnage breaks something? Say, a Friday afternoon change? I would have thought allowing Devs to create DB's would be less serious then allowing them to make changes in place. But hey, what do I know....

Comment: When they break something, they have to fix it by themselves. if a Restore is required then I do it. but it doesn't happened alot...

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in the following Database Roles as I don't think there is a Server Role that fulfils your requirements.

```
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_ddladmin
```

Then remove them from the `sysadmin` Server Role.

<strike>I think you can then issue `DENY` statements to prevent them from using the `CREATE`,`ALTER`,`DROP DATABASE` statements.</strike>

e.g.

`DENY CREATE DATABASE to UserXYZ`

I haven't tested this so I'm not 100% sure if this is possible.

If you don't give them `db_ddladmin` permission in the `master` database then they won't be able to create any new databases.

Comment: So i have to go over all the DB's and add all my developers to the db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin DB roles of each DB?

Comment: I think that would be best option here.  I am presuming that all of your developers are in single group that you can assign permissions too? You could create a script to do all the work for you and then just run across your DB's.

Comment: I'm not using WINDOWS NT permissions because the server is a remote one, not in my company's Domain.
Is there anyway to create a SQL group? and put SQL users in it?